# How does pyplot know what was plotted by the output of pandas.DataFrame(...).cumprod().plot()

Tags: python, pandas

I am coming from a background of C# programming to learn python, and trying to wrap my head around how things work.
There seems to be a lot of "magic" in getting the result you want in python.

For example, take the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

returns = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(1.0, 0.03, (100, 10)))
prices = returns.cumprod()
prices.plot()
plt.title('Randomly-generated Prices')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.legend(loc=0);
```

This produces a nifty line plot, very nice.
So we pass the output of numpy.random.normal(...) into pandas.DataFrame(...) to get, according to the docostring, the following assigned to the variable returns:
Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data
structure with labeled axes (rows and columns)

Then somehow that data structure contains a method returns.cumprod() which is called to get, according to the docstring, the following assigned to the variable prices:
Return cumulative cumprod over requested axis.

The next four lines of code, (how good would it be if notebook had line numbers), are calling methods of the matplotlib.pyplot lib.

**So my question is:**

As these are completely separate objects in separate namespaces, how does the matplotlib.pyplot know anything about what pandas.DataFrame(...).comprod(...).plot() just did.

Like in C# one object in one namespace knows nothing about another object in a separate namespace that it hasn't been explicitly told, via input methods.

So just trying to get my head around how this all works, so I can build things with a good design, instead of just copying and pasting stuff I google to find that look like they get the output I want.
Like how does scope work with the above code. Lets say I do two plots, how does it know which one to assign the title to?

Thanks for your time/patience,

Kind Regards.

Comment: Take a look at the stateful vs stateless approaches section of [this article](https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/#stateful-versus-stateless-approaches). Basically, `DataFrame.plot` creates a matplotlib object and functions like `plt.title` gets the "current" object (from the global namespace) and work on that.

Comment: @ayhan, thanks for the response.  I will check out the article.  I must say, I am not a fan of the design of having everything in a global namespace...

Comment: Yes, I think this approach is only kept for backward compatibility. The article also mentions the proper way of doing this (with the object oriented approach).

Comment: Oh fantastic, I will check it out ;-)

Comment: @ayhan, thanks for taking the time to suggest that article, it was fantastic, and filled in a lot of blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run for example plt.legend() it uses the function plt.gca() (get current axis) and since the pandas plot was the last axis plotted it knows where to put the legend. If you do, for example:

```
pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2], 'y': [2,3]}).plot.line()

pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2], 'y': [2,43]}).plot.line()

plt.legend([1])
```

It will plot the legend in the second axis since it was the current axis.

Comment: thanks for the response.  So after you have done two plots and you want to alter a property of the first one, how do you do that, if you are relying on a reference that is getting overwritten in the global namespace?

Comment: You have to save it, for instance you can do: ax = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2], 'y': [2,3]}).plot.line() and then ax.legend() to plot in this axis.

Comment: this is making sense.  Thanks for the clarification ;-)